# Mouse Re-centering in java

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mousemove, awtrobot

I'm writing a very basic first person game in java, and one problem I've been running into for a while was the mouse motion(eg, the cursor going out of the frame), so I decided to try and figure out how to use the `awt.Robot` class to recenter the mouse every time after it was moved. However, I ran into a problem that I'm getting really annoyed with and I feel like it should be really easy to fix: the mouse cursor either doesn't move or doesn't move long enough for the program to register it. This is my last attempt at it which is based on an example from a tutorial

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){ 
            MouseX = e.getX(); 
            MouseY = e.getY();
            try{
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.mouseMove((Frame.newX - Frame.oldX) + Frame.WIDTH / 2, (Frame.newY - Frame.oldY) + Frame.HEIGHT / 2);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

If it helps any, a good example of what I want to do is like in Minecraft, or actually almost any other first person game, where you can keep moving the mouse infinitely and the cursor stays in the middle of the frame.

Edit:

just realized this might be a bit confusing if I didn't tell you, `Frame` is the name of a separate class in the project, NOT `awt.Frame`, although some of you probably already figured that out from the way I used it.

Comment: AFAIK: games that show the cursor in the center either don't move the mouse cursor (yet evaluate the relative movement = bypassing the cursor positioning) or hide the actual mouse cursor and draw a fixed cross in the center while in that mode.

Comment: @zapl So what your saying is that I should set the mouse parameters to  stay inside the frame I created and then somehow make the mouse cursor invisible?

Comment: I'd try that. [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Game/MouselookTest.htm) is an example for robot centering the mouse but it looks terrible because the cursor is jumping. Hide it and it should be fine.

Comment: It's not good app courtesy to not allow the user to leave your game with his cursor. If that's what you're trying to do,... please don't.

Comment: I already have a mouse release key set to take care of that problem. I understand how annoying it can be for your mouse pointer to be stuck like that, but it's almost more annoying when it isn't sometimes.